# PHP multiple file upload will only upload the first 10 files selected (tried changing max_file_uploads) host says its my code?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, multifile-uploader

When I try to upload more than 10 images via...

index.php

```
<?php include("file-upload.php"); ?>
<div>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="mb-3">
      <div class="user-image mb-3 text-center">
        <div class="imgGallery"> 
          <!-- Image preview -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="custom-file">
        <input type="file" name="fileUpload[]" class="custom-file-input" id="chooseFile" multiple>
        <label class="custom-file-label" for="chooseFile">Select image files</label>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block mt-4">
        Upload Images
      </button>
    </form>
    <!-- Display response messages -->
    <?php if(!empty($response)) {?>
        <div class="alert <?php echo $response["status"]; ?>">
           <?php echo $response["message"]; ?>
        </div>
    <?php }?>
  </div>
  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
    // Multiple images preview with JavaScript
    var multiImgPreview = function(input, imgPreviewPlaceholder) {

        if (input.files) {
            var filesAmount = input.files.length;

            for (i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function(event) {
                    $($.parseHTML('<img>')).attr('src', event.target.result).appendTo(imgPreviewPlaceholder);
                }

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
            }
        }

    };

      $('#chooseFile').on('change', function() {
        multiImgPreview(this, 'div.imgGallery');
      });
    });    
  </script>
```

file-upload.php

```
// Database
include 'config/database.php'; 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    
    $uploadsDir = "uploads/";
    $allowedFileType = array('jpg','png','jpeg');
    
    // Velidate if files exist
    if (!empty(array_filter($_FILES['fileUpload']['name']))) {
        
        // Loop through file items
        foreach($_FILES['fileUpload']['name'] as $id=>$val){
            // Get files upload path
            $uploadDate4file      = date('dmYHis');
            $fileName        = $_FILES['fileUpload']['name'][$id];
            $tempLocation    = $_FILES['fileUpload']['tmp_name'][$id];
            $targetFilePath  = $uploadsDir . $uploadDate4file . $fileName;
            $fileType        = strtolower(pathinfo($targetFilePath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
            $uploadDate      = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $uploadOk = 1;

            if(in_array($fileType, $allowedFileType)){
                    if(move_uploaded_file($tempLocation, $targetFilePath)){
                        $sqlVal = "('".$fileName."', '".$uploadDate."')";
                    } else {
                        $response = array(
                            "status" => "alert-danger",
                            "message" => "File could not be uploaded."
                        );
                    }
                
            } else {
                $response = array(
                    "status" => "alert-danger",
                    "message" => "Only .jpg, .jpeg and .png file formats allowed."
                );
            }
            // Add into MySQL database
            if(!empty($sqlVal)) {
                $insert = $conn->query("INSERT INTO productimages (images, date_time) VALUES $sqlVal");
                if($insert) {
                    $response = array(
                        "status" => "alert-success",
                        "message" => "Images successfully uploaded."
                    );
                        ///Prints $rmfirstclassuk as array 
                        
echo "Images uploaded: ".$_FILES['fileUpload']['name'].", ";
echo "<pre>";
print_r ($_FILES['fileUpload']['name']);
echo "</pre>";
                    
                } else {
                    $response = array(
                        "status" => "alert-danger",
                        "message" => "Images couldn't be uploaded due to database error."
                    );
                }
            }
        }

    } else {
        // Error
        $response = array(
            "status" => "alert-danger",
            "message" => "Please select image files to upload."
        );
    }
}
```

database.php

```
$hostname = "HIDDEN";
$username = "HIDDEN";
$password = "HIDDEN";
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=mydbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    //echo "Database connected successfully";
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Database connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

...only the first 10 ever actually upload.

On reading other answers on here I have changed max_file_uploads to 50 on the PHP Configuration page and also tried ini_set('max_file_uploads', 50); on the page itself but try as I might I can't get it to upload more than 10 files.

Note: despite me trying to set the limit to 50 I only actually want to upload 12 at a time so I'm falling just 2 short!

So then I contacted my host with the issue who first tried upping my max_file_uploads to 100 and asked me to try again but when that didn't work have now said...

> I've checked this further. It doesn't look to be an issue with the
> server block I've both our mod security rule and server restrictions
> but all looks to be allowing it. It does seem to be that the code is
> preventing this from working.

but as much as I look over the code I can't see anything that would be preventing more than 10 files uploading, any ideas please?

Comment: On PHP 5.3.1+ even if you have `max_file_uploads` directive set to a bigger number to allow more uploads in a request, without an increase in `post_max_size` directive, the total size of files may exceed allowed limit and will fail. So what is the size of `post_max_size` and you 10 files size?

Comment: @Akinak PHP version is 7.4, the combined file size for the 12 png image files I am uploading is 5.02mb, the post_max_size is currently set to 1024M

Comment: do `echo phpInfo();` and check if the setting for `max_file_uploads` and `post_max_size` are actually the values you expect

Comment: @WesleySmith good shout, when I check this way I can see that despite my host saying they have changed the setting from there end max-file-uploads is indeed still set to 10 so back to them I go. Am I wrong in thinking the support I got was not very good given they said they had 1st changed the setting, then double-checked it, then blamed my code?

Comment: Honestly, the support you got is pretty typical of most hosting options I've used, especially if its a shared hosting situation. These types of environments get complicated and most customer service folks, even for hosting companies, just dont have the technical knowledge to accurately answer some questions.